# About apps script intialization for google slides

Tags: google-apps-script

Here as per the docs

// Open a presentation by ID.
var preso = SlidesApp.openById('PRESENTATION_ID_GOES_HERE');

// Create and open a presentation.
preso = SlidesApp.create('Presentation Name');
\

how to get the SlidesApp from script using nodejs

this is my script

const script = google.script({ version: "v1", auth: oauth2Client });

Here i need to get the SlidesApp which i open google slides by url

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)